# Passing parameter from Angular to ASP.NET MVC Controller and displaying the data using Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass the parameter from Angular to ASP.NET MVC Controller and I need some help with this. First I had problems even with passing the parameter because I always had null in my action method in MVC controller. I already solved it but another problem is with getting data from MVC and displaying it with Angular in the right html template. I tried a lot to solve this problem, I was looking for any solution but the result is still the same. Here is my code:

MVC Controller (GenreController)

```
public JsonResult GetGameList(string genrename)
    {
        if (genrename != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var genre = db.Genres.Include("Games").Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == genrename.ToLower()).SingleOrDefault();
                var gameslist = genre.Games.ToList();
                return Json(gameslist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception("Something bad happened!", ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(null);
        }

    }
```

Here is my angularjs app:

```
var app = angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'GenreController', 'HomeController', 'AccountController'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/genres/:genrename', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/genre.html',
                controller: 'GenreCtrl'
            })
            .when('/account/login', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                controller: 'AccountCtrl'
            })
            .when('/account/register', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
                controller: 'AccountCtrl'
            })
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });
```

GenreCtrl:

```
angular.module('GenreController', [])
       .controller('GenreCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
           $scope.genres = {};
           $scope.gameslist = {};
           $scope.msg = "AngularJS";

           //get genres for navbar
           $http.get('/Home/GetGenres').success(function (data) {
               $scope.genres = data;
           }).error(function (err) {
               console.log(err);
           });

           //here is probably the problem
           var response = $http({
               method: "get",
               url: "/Genre/GetGameList",
               params: {
                   genrename: $routeParams.genrename
               },
               success: function (data) {
                   $scope.gameslist = data;
               }
           });

           $scope.genrename = $routeParams.genrename; 
       }]);
```

Debugging and 2 console errors:

[image: Debugging]

[image]

In the html template I'm just doing something like this for see if I can get the data or not

```
<div ng-repeat="game in gameslist">
    <h1>{{game.Price}}</h1>
</div>
```

I think it might be something wrong with success in response but maybe you guys have some solution for this.

//Update, here is the server side debugging:

[image: Server-side-debugging]

**//Update - the problem solution**

Okay, so I spent a lot of time on it but it's finally working. Maybe not exactly what I wanted but for now that's okay. First I had to add `JsonConvert` to my server side action method. It's returning this object with JSON `AllowGet`. Then I added `GetGenreByName` action method that returns the name of specified genre (you can do this also in `GetGameList` action method if you want instead of creating seperated action but I think this is just better to have `GetGenreByName` action seperated from others). Also in Angular controller I `changed` my success to `then` and I had to parse my data using `JSON.parse`. Here is my working code:

MVC Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get(string genrename)
        {
            try
            {
                var results = GetGenreByName(genrename);
                if (results == null)
                {
                    return Json(null);
                }
                else
                {


    var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results.Games, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                });

                 return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(ex, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }


public Genre GetGenreByName(string gname)
{
    return db.Genres.Include("Games").Where(x => x.Name == gname).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Angular controller:

```
   $http({
       url: '/Genre/Get',
       params: {
           genrename: $routeParams.genrename
       },
       method: 'get'
   }).then(function (response) {
       $scope.list = JSON.parse(response.data);
   });
```

and ng-repeat to check if all is working.

```
<div ng-repeat="game in list">
    <h2>{{game.GameTitle}}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: When you debug your server code. At which line does it crash?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the catch{...} block

Comment: Server side is not getting any errors. Just these 2 errors in the console.

Comment: But http status 500 means that the server controller crashed. You have the flag [AllowGet] ?

Comment: I prefer `return new JsonResult(){Data=..};` Maybe not the value `null` as `Data`.

Comment: Hint try typing into the address line of Firefox `http//localhost:58867/Genre/GetGameList?genrename=Sport` . Firefox know will show you the JSON data, if the server does not crash.

Comment: Problem solved. Updated my post with more details about the solution.